# How to avoid a backgroung to repeat itself - but to expand and occupy all the bkgrd?

Tags: css, xhtml

I would like to use an image as background. Unfortunately, when I set the *Background-image* property to *url(myUrl)*, I get the image which repeats itself in the background in several row and column. I guess it's because the image its naturally small.

So, how to get the image to expends enough so that it does not repeat itself, but rather occupies all the back ground?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use two methods;
javascript or css

Jquery has a solution called suppersized;
http://buildinternet.com/2009/02/supersized-full-screen-backgroundslideshow-jquery-plugin/

or with CSS:

```
html, body {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
body {font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size:76%;}
#background{position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

AND HTML

```
<body>
<div>
<img id="background" src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Looks like the simplest way.

P.S.: You can't do it with pure background-image. You have to do it with different layer.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent an image from repeating itself, and adjust the image size to fit the screen size, the following two CSS instructions will help out:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the property **[background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size)** in CSS3 for stretching a background image. But CSS3 isn't widely supported.

If you don't want to repeat the background image then you can use `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from [W3Scools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp) using CSS:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://marketplace.canva.com/BAAuU/MAD4tNBAAuU/1/s2/canva-egg-and-ceramic-rabbit-MAD4tNBAAuU.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bg"></div>

  <p>This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>

</body>

</html>
```